# How to convert/cast SqlDataReader to IDatareader

Tags: c#, .net, idatareader

What is the easiest way to cast a SqlDataReader to IDatareader.

Or is it easier / possible to convert a List<> object to a IDataReader

Comment: `SqlDataReader` already implements `IDataReader`. Could you post some code to show the actual problem you're having?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the easiest way to convert a SqlDataReader to IDatareader

Since `SqlDataReader` implements `IDataReader`, this is just an implicit cast:

```
SqlDataReader typedReader = ...
IDataReader untypedReader = typedReader;
```

Answer (score 3):

A `SqlDataReader` *is* an `IDataReader` (it implements the interface), so you don't have to convert it at all. Anywhere your code expects an `IDataReader`, you can use the Sql implementation.

```
// Given a method with this signature
public void ProcessData(IDataReader reader);

// You can do this
SqlDataReader sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();
ProcessData(sqlReader);
```

---

As for `List<T>` and `IDataReader`: apart from being enumerable these do very different things. The most conspicuous difference is that data readers offer access to columnar data (primarily because it implements the `IDataRecord` interface), which doesn't make sense for most lists.

You *could* implement an adapter that provides access to a `List<T>` through the data reader interface, but it would be a poor fit and a fair amount of work.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the easiest way to convert a
>   SqlDataReader to IDatareader

You can not. A `SqlDataReader` CLASS is not an `IDataReader` interfadce.

For casting (assign to variable) use

```
IDataReader untypedReader = typedReader;
```

BUT: this is NOT a conversion. It is a cast. A conversion to an inteerface is per defintiion not possible as interfaces can not be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just cast it, but as has been stated, it's largely unnecessary unless you're creating or using a generic interface since all the properties and methods of `IDbDataReader` is available to `SqlDataReader`.

```
((IDbDataReader)typedReader).SomeMethod();
```

Comment: that isn't really boxing (well, if `SomeMethod` returns a struct that implements `IDbReader` it might, but that seems unlikely)

Comment: @Marc, sorry for the typo. I needed more parens.

Comment: parens are better, but that still isn't boxing... boxing is when a value-type is coerced into a reference-type container (`object` or an interface that isn't constrained via generics)

Comment: @Marc, ah... that's correct. I've updated to `cast` instead of `box`. Thanks! That more appropriate?